# Add dynamically TinyMCE Textarea on Newly tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, tinymce, jquery-ui-tabs

I using tab's JQuery plugin UI each tab contains TextArea then are manage by TinyMCE librarie.

I want to do : When you click on tab "+" , that add new tab which contains textarea too.
To create new tab with textearea , it's good. The problem is : I can't edit textarea value and if i click on TinyMCE 's option ( like Bold ) : **J is null** error on Javascript console

My JS Code :

```
$('li > a.moretxt').click(function(){

    // Number of element in tabs
    var size = $( "#tabs" ).tabs("length"); 
    // Content to add on new tab
    var content = "<div id='divcontent"+size+"'><textarea id=\'txtcontent"+size+"'\' cols=\'60\' rows=\'5\'></textarea></div>";
    // Some variable
    var path = '#divcontent'+size;
    var title = 'content'+size;
    var idtxt = 'txtcontent'+size;
    // Add new div Textarea before the end
    $('div#morecontent').before(content);
    //Add control ?
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, idtxt);
    // Add new TAB
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs("add",path,title,(size));
    var index = $( "#tabs" ).tabs("option", "selected");


});
```

The follow code , well add tab with tiny TextArea but it doesn't works ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE needs to have the object in the DOM to apply itself. I'm not sure why TinyMCE isn't working as you appear to be are adding the container prior to adding TinyMCE, however if you move the "addControl" to after you've added the new Tab it should work.